# Avoiding file access permission in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me

I have developed a J2ME application in which the application reads files from the Memory Card. Those are audio files to be specific. I need to supress the propmts which occure everytime when the audio files are accessed. I am using NetBeans 6.8 and tried signing it to be trusted in the properties. It didn't work.

Can someone Pls help..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have sign is limited to your system for not asking for permition
when you are implementing those application on mobile device at that time
you require signing certificates

following are  trusted 3rd party domain through which you can sign application

- **Thawte**
- **Verisign**

for more reference follow [this](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Java_Security_Domains) link.

Answer (score 2):

You need your app. running in trusted domain for that , than you can specify that for file IO "**ask once**"

**Also See**

- [J2ME Security](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/permissions/)